# How to specify Metaplex NFT collection image in Phantom wallet

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, phantom-wallet

I've created a Solana NFT through metaplex. 1 out of 1.
It's showing up in my Phantom wallet on mobile however it's different from the NFTs purchased on solanart.

On the NFT screen, it says "Collection NFT" and shows the actual image only if I tap into the collection (last one).

What should I do to make it look like the purchased ones?
Also somehow another unspecified and empty (no metadata) NFT is also there and I'm not sure what it is (third one in the list).
Quite new to this, so probably missing something simple...

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of Phantom]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding the "Collection NFT"  - You have to manually add metadata to the NFT:

1. Upload a new JSON + PNG pair (e.g. with arloader, sol-nft.tools arkb). It should can look like any other NFT metadata but should contain the collection data that will be shown.
2. use `cli-nft.ts create-metadata` or `metaboss` to add the uri (from the step 1) to the collection nft mint
3. **Update June 2022:** There is now a way better method to updating single NFTs:

- Search your collection adress (Open a NFT on solscan, look into the metadata tab. There is a "collection" value which is your collection address). Copy it.
- go to https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/update-nft and connect your wallet
- enter the collection address
- Modify whatever you need

Regarding the third NFT in your list: It looks like that you did not verify the upload and therefore the data was not on chain when the token was minted. Have a look here: https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/verify-upload

Comment: Hey. Thank you, setting the collection field on the metadata, uploading to arweave and using cli-nft update-metadata did help!