# Does anyone know how to make my solana collection connect with opensea?

Tags: smartcontracts, nft, metaplex, opensea, candy-machine

well the matter is the following.

I want to connect my collection to opensea, my collection is created in the candy machine v2 and I want that when connecting my collection with opensea the minted NFTs automatically connect with the collection in opensea.

I know that when certifying it, it is uploaded manually, but I think it is not appropriate when talking about creating collections of more than 1,000 NFTs.

So it would be very helpful if someone knows how to make the collection upload mined NFTs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A collection through candy machine nowadays automatically is a Metaplex Certified Collection (MCC).

Please check in the On Chain Metadata (e.g. on solscan) if it's the case for you.

- if you already have a collection make sure that the address that you see in the metadata as collection key has metadata. If it's just shown with name "Collection NFT" make sure to attach metadata through it e.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72071604/how-to-specify-metaplex-nft-collection-image-in-phantom-wallet/72097315#72097315)
- If there is no collection key present for your NFTs you should use metaboss or [collections.metaplex.com](https://collections.metaplex.com/) to migrate.

Comment: will this work when an nft is minted to connect automatically with opensea?

Comment: Opensea automatically indexes collections and NFTs, yes. You have to make sure that the collection NFT has metadata though.